# Truncate a string saving HTML tags structure

Tags: php, html, truncate

I want to truncate a string that contains html tags saving it's structure.

Example:

```
Hello! My name is Jerald and here is a link to my <a href="#">Blog</a>.
```

So if i set max characters of it's substring to 52, i expecting it to return string like following:

```
Hello! My name is Jerald and here is a link to my <a href="#">Bl</a>
```

I tried to use `strip_tags` and `strlen` function to count text without and with html tags and than set new length of substring (size without + size with html tags). But this method is breaking html string.

Comment: Why not do it using CSS? It is better doing this using ellipsis than truncating and making a data loss.

Comment: You could want to do it in PHP for example if you have a HTML item (like news/blog post) and you then want to print a teaser of the item. You could of course truncate like normal but it could stop in the middle of some html block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this, not my code but can't find where I found it originally:

```
function truncateHTML($html_string, $length, $append = '&hellip;', $is_html = true) {
  $html_string = trim($html_string);
  $append = (strlen(strip_tags($html_string)) > $length) ? $append : '';
  $i = 0;
  $tags = [];

  if ($is_html) {
    preg_match_all('/<[^>]+>([^<]*)/', $html_string, $tag_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach($tag_matches as $tag_match) {
      if ($tag_match[0][1] - $i >= $length) {
        break;
      }

      $tag = substr(strtok($tag_match[0][0], " \t\n\r\0\x0B>"), 1);
      if ($tag[0] != '/') {
        $tags[] = $tag;
      }
      elseif (end($tags) == substr($tag, 1)) {
        array_pop($tags);
      }

      $i += $tag_match[1][1] - $tag_match[0][1];
    }
  }

  return substr($html_string, 0, $length = min(strlen($html_string), $length + $i)) . (count($tags = array_reverse($tags)) ? '</' . implode('></', $tags) . '>' : '') . $append;
}
```

Example:

```
$my_input_with_html = 'Hello! My name is Jerald and here is a link to my <a href="#">Blog</a>.';
$my_output_with_correct_html = truncateHTML($my_input_with_html, 52);
```

Gives you:

```
Hello! My name is Jerald and here is a link to my <a href="#">Bl</a>&hellip;
```

Demo: https://eval.in/832674

Hope this helps.